# $F[x]$-modules and their relation to $F$-vector spaces

Tags: abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules

Suppose that $F$ is a field and consider the $F[x]$-module $(V,f)$, with $V$ an $F$-vector space and $f\in\operatorname{End}_F(V)$ a linear operator.

**Q1.** The most common way to define $f$ is by setting $f(v):=x\cdot v$. Are there other possible definitions that will yield a different module structure?

Now, let's suppose that $V$ is a finite dimensional vector space over $F$.

**Q2.** Under this condition, can we guarantee that this $F[x]$-module is finitely generated?

Thanks.

Comment: $V$ is a $F$-module (= $F$ vector space) so once you know it and the $F$-module endomorphism (= $F$-linear map) $f: v\to x.v$ you have a unique $F[x]$-module structure on $V$

Comment: It should be written $x\cdot v := f(v)$ not the other way around, and it's the action of $x$ that is defined this way not $f$.

Comment: If you already have an $F[x]-$module $(V,f)$ with a fixed $f\in \mathrm{End}(V)$, then it doesn't make sense to define $f$.

Comment: Yes, you're right. $(V,f)$ is an $F[x]$-module, with a scalar multiplication $F[x]\times V\to V$. Since, for example, $x^2\in F[x]$, it is possible to consider 'the action of $x^2$' on the elements of $V$. How is this defined? $x^2\cdot v = x(x\cdot v)=xf(v)$? Does the definition $x\cdot v:= f(v)$ fix all other possible outcomes (i.e. $x^2\cdot v$ or $(6x^3+1)\cdot v$?).